# Chrome Developer Tools SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' when refreshing page

Tags: typescript, vue-router, vite

When using TypeScript v5.3.3 in a Vue v3.4.19 project bundled by Vite v5.1.3 the following code:

```
import { ContentPiece, ContentCategory } from "internal-library";

export interface ContentCategoryWithContentPieces extends ContentCategory {
  contentPieces: Array<ContentPiece>;
}
```

Produced a dev bundle with the source:

```js
export type ContentCategoryWithContentPieces = ContentCategory & {
  contentPieces: Array<ContentPiece>;
};
```

Which causes the following error when Chrome dev tools are open and the page is refreshed:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' (at ContentCategoryUtils.ts:7:1)`

**Note**: Although this may not be relevant, the error was thrown by the Vue Router v4.2.5.  `[Vue Router warn]: uncaught error during route navigation`

Answer (score 0):

Problem appears to occur because of the `isloatedModules` mode ([recommended by Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features#typescript-compiler-options)). The new [Type-Only Imports and Exports syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-and-export) is recommended to exclude types from being included in the build output.

As the `"internal-library"` is a list of TypeScript interfaces, the code should be as follows:

```
import type { ContentPiece, ContentCategory } from "internal-library";

export interface ContentCategoryWithContentPieces extends ContentCategory {
  contentPieces: Array<ContentPiece>;
}
```

And where this interface is used in other components, it should be imported with the `type` keyword:

```
import type { ContentCategoryWithContentPieces } from "@/types/content";
```